# Grouping an already sorted file in parquet format

Tags: python, parquet

I have several data files ~ 1TB each uncompressed in csv format

```
time,id,data1,data2,...
t1,0,x1,y1
t2,0,x2,y2
t8,0,x3,y3
t7,1,x4,y1
t9,1,x4,y2
t4,3,x5,y3
t6,3,x5,y3
```

They are sorted *first* on the second column and then on the first column, so all similar `id` rows are next to each other.

I need to randomly access the rows for each `id`, like so

```
get_id(data, id)
```

I currently do this by a binary search with fseek into the uncompressed raw csv text file, but I would like to be able to do this with a compressed file format.

I have created a parquet file with the data with `pandas` and `pyarrow`.

Q: *How can I now read one id without having to scan through the entire data set?*

Since the data is already sorted, I don't want to have to search through the entire data set for matching `id`.

Comment: If you want direct access, you'd better use a sqlite database and index your data.

Answer (score 0):

The Parquet format does not allow arbitrary random access, but it allows efficient filtering based on statistics embedded in the Parquet files. This is usually called predicate push-down.

The Java API provides the [UserDefinedPredicate](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-column/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/filter2/predicate/UserDefinedPredicate.java) class for this purpose. A short excerpt from the Javadoc of this class:

> A UserDefinedPredicate decides whether a record should be kept or dropped, first by inspecting meta data about a group of records to see if the entire group can be dropped, then by inspecting actual values of a single column.

Unfortunately I don't think that this functionality is provided by any Python binding at this moment.